# Fill out the background color

Tags: html, css

Goal:
Mouse hovering over the picture and its area, the title and content will raise up.
The contents background and height should go to the bottom of the area.

Problem:
The title and contents background don't go all the way down to the button.
I don't know how to do.
Please take a look at the picture for visual communication.

JSBin:
https://jsbin.com/xenavotemu/edit?html,output

Thank you!

[image]

```css
.cards {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
  transition: border 1s;
  position: relative;
}

.card:hover {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.card .wrapper {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  width: 100%;
}

.card:hover .wrapper {
  bottom: 30px;
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}

.cardTitle {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -4px;
  color: white;
  background-color: grey;
  font-size: xx-large;
}

.cardText {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.card:hover .cardText {
  height: 100%;
  ;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.responsive {
  width: 300px;
}


/* 2 column */

@media (min-width: 700px) and (max-width: 899px) {
  div.cards {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}


/* 3 columns */

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  div.cards {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://dogtowndogtraining.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/300x300-061-e1340955308953.jpg" class="responsive" alt="" />
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="cardTitle">ONE</div>
      <div class="cardText">aaa<br /> aaaa</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://dogtowndogtraining.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/300x300-061-e1340955308953.jpg" class="responsive" alt="" />
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="cardTitle">ONE</div>
      <div class="cardText">aaa<br /> aaa<br /> aaa</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://dogtowndogtraining.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/300x300-061-e1340955308953.jpg" class="responsive" alt="" />
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="cardTitle">ONE</div>
      <div class="cardText">aaa<br /> aaa<br /> aaa<br /> aaa</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you might need to change your markup a bit (and eventually the `CSS` as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the technic from this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8331169/10839134

Removed following style because it's causing the height problem.

```
.card:hover .wrapper {
  bottom: 30px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Instead of changing the `visibility` on `.cardText` I change the `max-height`:

```
.cardText {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
}

.card:hover .cardText {
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 500px;
  transition: max-height 0.25s ease-in;
}
```

https://jsbin.com/xowematuki/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to put the image inside it's own wrapper that will shrink from the bottom up (from 100% to 70% in this example). Of course, all overflow hidden.

```css
.cards {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
  transition: border 1s;
  position: relative;
}

.card:hover {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.card .wrapper {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  width: 100%;
}

.card:hover .wrapper {
  bottom: 30px;
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}

.cardTitle {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -4px;
  color: white;
  background-color: grey;
  font-size: xx-large;
}

.cardText {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.card:hover .cardText {
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.responsive {
  width: 300px;
}

.img-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.card:hover .img-wrapper {
  height: 70%;
}

.card {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <img src="https://dogtowndogtraining.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/300x300-061-e1340955308953.jpg" class="responsive" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="cardTitle">ONE</div>
      <div class="cardText">aaa<br /> aaaa</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```